# VueJS toggle password visibilty without mutating the "type" property

Tags: vue.js, passwords, obfuscation, vue-props

I have a basic input component I am working with that has `type` as a property and up until now has been working very well. However, trying to use it for passwords and implementing obfuscation has been sort of tricky.

How can I toggle hide/show of the password without mutating the prop? I figured making it `type = 'password'` to `type = 'text` was the best way, but clearly not.

I've made a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-cache-4y0jv?file=/src/components/PasswordInput.vue) to replicate that part of the component, but any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated!

**PasswordInput.vue:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input :type="type" />
    <button @click="obfuscateToggle" class="ml-auto pl-sm _eye">
      <div>
        <img :src="`/${eyeSvg}.svg`" alt="" />
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      passwordVisible: false,
      eyeSvg: "eye-closed",
    };
  },
  props: {
    type: { type: String, default: "text" },
  },
  methods: {
    obfuscateToggle() {
      if (this.eyeSvg === "eye-closed") {
        this.eyeSvg = "eye";
      } else this.eyeSvg = "eye-closed";
      // this.eyeSvg = "eye-closed" ? "" : (this.eyeSvg = "eye");
      if ((this.type = "password")) {
        this.type = "text";
      } else this.type = "password";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <PasswordInput type="password" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do it is by mutating the type attribute. As that is how the browser decides the render it as either just a textbox or as a password. Therefore you are doing this *the right way*.

The one issue that you will encounter is that you will have errors thrown in your console because you are attempting to mutate a prop.

This is quick and easy to fix. First, you will create a new data property, and assign it to the default of `type`

```js
data(){
   return{
      fieldType:'text'
   }
}
```

Then you will use the on [`mounted` lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), and update your data property to match your prop's value`

```js
mounted(){
   this.fieldType = this.type;
}
```

If you know the `type` prop will change from the parent component you can also use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for changes and assign `type`

```js
watch:{
   type(val){
      this.fieldType = val;
   }
}
```

You will then update your `obfuscateToggle` method to use the fieldtype variable:

```js
obfuscateToggle() {
  if (this.eyeSvg === "eye-closed") {
    this.eyeSvg = "eye";
  } else this.eyeSvg = "eye-closed";


  //You can simplify this by using this.fieldType = this.fieldType == "text" ? "password" : "text"
  if (this.fieldType == "password") {
    this.fieldType = "text";
  } else this.fieldType = "password";
}
```

Finally, in your template, you will want to change `type` to `fieldType`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input :type="fieldType" />
    <button @click="obfuscateToggle" class="ml-auto pl-sm _eye">
      <div>
        <img :src="`/${eyeSvg}.svg`" alt="" />
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Putting it all together

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      passwordVisible: false,
      eyeSvg: "eye-closed",
      fieldType: "text"
    };
  },
  props: {
    type: { type: String, default: "text" },
  },
  methods: {
    obfuscateToggle() {
      if (this.eyeSvg === "eye-closed") {
        this.eyeSvg = "eye";
      } else this.eyeSvg = "eye-closed";
 

      //You can simplify this by using this.fieldType = this.fieldType == "text" ? "password" : "text"
      if (this.fieldType == "password") {
        this.fieldType = "text";
      } else this.fieldType = "password";


    },
  },
  watch:{
    type(val){
       this.fieldType = val;
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.fieldType = this.type;
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is an example on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-68602902-zfixi?file=/src/components/PasswordInput.vue)

---

Also, you had a small typo in your `obfuscateToggle` method.

```
if(this.type = 'password')
```

this was assigning `type` instead of comparing it against a literal :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the edit and the comment here; you really went all out. I definitely learned something today and it's relieving that I wasn't too far off haha